# WPF move focus from UserControl To Parent View

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, combobox, focus

I have a user control inside of a view. The usercontrol has a combobox and a few text boxes, with a button. When the button is clicked inside the usercontrol, I would like the focus to go to the Submit button on the parent view instead of the combobox in the usercontrol. I appreciate any advice I can get.

```
<Grid>
    <userControls:myControl etc.../>
    <Button etc..../>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FocusManager.FocusedElement](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=focusmanager%20focused%20element) to achieve this. Set this to your Control

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=MyButtonName}">
   <UserControls:myControl etc.../>
   <Button Name="MyButtonName"/>
</Grid >
```